# Force iframe YouTube video to center fit and full cover the screen in the background using HTML5 CSS3

Tags: html, css, video, background, youtube-iframe-api

How do you force HTML5 `iframe` YouTube video to center fit, cover the full-screen window background using CSS3 HTML eventually Java?

As for example "*[paypal.it](http://paypal.it)*" home page background or "*[unity3d.com/5](http://unity3d.com/5)*" top video, has as iframe youtube video.
The `iframe` covers the full screen (zooming) and covers all the width and height when re-size the window.
It re-size maintaining the 100% min-width zooming the height or the 100% min-height zooming the width.

How is this effect achieve using `iframe` HTML5 and CSS3?

Code Example HTML5

```
<div class="video" style="opacity: 1;">

    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AddHereVideoId?autoplay=1&amp;html5=1" frameborder="0" style="height: 720px;">
     </iframe>

</div>
```

Code CSS3 HTML eventually Java help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For a real full screen solution, this can be achieved like this:

HTML

```
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I4agXcHLySs?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.vid-info { width: 50%; padding: .5rem; }
.vid-info h1 { margin-bottom: .2rem; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.vid-info .acronym { display: none; }
}
```

It is not perfect, e.g. it does not work well with extreme aspect ratios of the container, but is doing a great job in most situations. Here is a working example:

https://codepen.io/hnrchrdl/pen/YzPwjBV

**Edit**: Check [Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192837/2024590), he seems to have an improved version of this solution.

Comment: Just an FYI, this doesn't work when placed inside a carousel or something that's moving - the outer fixed element will bring headaches.

Comment: @JCraine Works fine for me inside a carousel. Just make sure you've got a set height for your carousel slides and the video area is an inner container with the specified attributes from this demo. I am using the Glide.js plugin and it works great!

Comment: @Hinrich, hey there. Two years later I have a problem.

Comment: @Hinrich, when you go into F11/Fullscreen mode on Windows 10 Chrome, the video gets zoomed in by 20% in this solution.. decreasing the field of view and video quality. Anyone have ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Perfect... well, nearly. After recent Youtube changes, the loop doesn't work anymore without adding `&playlist=<VIDEO_ID>` to the end of the url. The VIDEO_ID in the example above would be "I4agXcHLySs". After adding that... Perfect.

Answer (score 65):

## Full-size YouTube video, all aspect ratios, CSS only

TL:DR - [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohepworthbell/k72hbytr/)

As an update/improvement to @Hinrich's answer, I have created a CSS-only scaler that works for ALL aspect ratios - even the extremes. Rather than over-compensating the width to fit most screen sizes, the iframe is set using `vw` and `vh` and offset using the CSS `transform` property (which offsets relative to the element, not the parent).

Most browsers (IE9+ and all evergreen browsers AFAIK) support the `vw` and `vh` units, as well as `transform`s, so this should work for pretty much all browsers *with no JavaScript required*.

```css
.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-background iframe {
    /* height = 100 * (9 / 16) = 56.25 */
    height: 56.25vw;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-background iframe {
    /* width = 100 / (9 / 16) = 177.777777 */
    width: 177.78vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/biWk-QLWY7U?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

## With CSS variables

For those using CSS variables, you can also [do this (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ohepworthbell/62ktqs1j/), which lets you arbitrarily reuse the sizes for multiple classnames:

```css
:root {
  --video-width: 100vw;
  --video-height: 100vh;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  :root {
    --video-height: 56.25vw;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  :root {
    --video-width: 177.78vh;
  }
}

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: var(--video-width);
  height: var(--video-height);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Why does this not have more votes??

Comment: This is simply perfect

Comment: @Oliver, in F11/Fullscreen mode on Windows 10 Chrome Browser, the video becomes 20% zoomed in when going into this fullscreen mode. Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks so much.

Comment: @PaulMcBurney at a guess I'd assume you have a small 4:3 or 16:10 screen, but outside fullscreen mode the browser address bar brings the inner window to closer to 16:9. In full-screen, the video zooms to fit the 4:3 aspect ratio? Does this happen on any other browser for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Oliver.. still fixing this problem. It happens on Windows and Edge, Firefox is fine.

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, but it did. Simply magic

Comment: For my needs I modified `.video-background` to `height: 100%;` so if the page can be scrolled and 100vh is less than 100%, the video will be still as a cover inside the div.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
.video-wrapper {position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  padding-top: 25px;}
.video-wrapper iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

<div class="video-wrapper">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AddHereVideoId?autoplay=1&amp;html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

This will give you a video that fills the container that it is in and will automatically scale the height too.

I originally found this solution here: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: This gives full screen width, but it does not zoom in, so it is not complete fullscreen for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not zoom in"?

Comment: It is not really fullsize, that means there is a border around the video. it scales to width or height, but not both at the time.

Comment: You need to change the `padding-bottom` of the wrapper to match the aspect ratio of the video being used. The example code is for a video at 16:9 but if you are using a video with a different ratio, then it will need calculating. See here for advice on calculating ratios: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/