# How to fit Youtube video size with div container

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have initialized a youtube video with youtube apis in a div with certain dimensions. Is it possible to display the video as it would be an image set as background sized cover of a div? I mean without any black spaces.

Here below you can find the actual result and the code I used.
[image: Image with black spaces]

Code:

```
var player123;

if(jQuery('#player123')){
    bindVideo();
}



function bindVideo(){

    var playerHeight = "500px";
    if(jQuery(window).width() < 1023){
        playerHeight = "100%";
    }else{
        playerHeight = "400px";
    }
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if(jQuery(window).width() < 1023){
            playerHeight = "100%";
        }else{
            playerHeight = "400px";
        }
    });
    player123 = new YT.Player('player123', {
        height: playerHeight,
        width: '100%',
        videoId: 'video-id-here',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady(event),
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },
        playerVars:{
            rel:0,
            loop:1,
            showinfo:0,
            controls:0,
            disablekb:1
        }
    });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == "2"){
        pauseVideo();
    }else if(event.data == "0"){
        stopVideo();
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    jQuery("#player-overlay").show();
    player123.stopVideo();
}
function PlayVideo2(){
    jQuery("#player-overlay").hide();
    player123.playVideo();
}
function pauseVideo(){
    jQuery("#player-overlay").show();
    player123.pauseVideo();
}
```

Is there any parameter to set to remove them ?

Answer (score 11):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579785/force-iframe-youtube-video-to-center-fit-and-full-cover-the-screen-in-the-backgr). This code will give you a video that fills the container that it is in and will automatically scale the height too.

```
.video-wrapper {position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  padding-top: 25px;}
.video-wrapper iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

<div class="video-wrapper">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AddHereVideoId?autoplay=1&amp;html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Additional references:

- [Fluid Width Video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)
- [Shrink a YouTube video to responsive width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width)