# Youtube iframe - zoom to fill the whole space

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I want to create a sort of banner in my webpage with a youtube video as background that should occupy the entire iframe from side to side (stretching the video and losing some pieces would be ok). Something like `background-size: cover;` would do. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579785/force-iframe-youtube-video-to-center-fit-and-full-cover-the-screen-in-the-backgr) but it's not really working (i can only see a really small stripe of video) in my case, probably because the format of my iframe is a little bit extreme.

```
<header id="banner">
    <div class="overlay">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N9Y86YCRRDg?&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=N9Y86YCRRDg&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;mute=1" width="100%" height="315"></iframe>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I pasted your source into their snippet and it worked for me, except where the content was clipped in the video frame

Comment: How big do you want this video banner to be? Pixels or percent of the page?

Comment: @TimOgilvy 100% width and the height fixed in pixels

Comment: So you'll need to make the percentage overflow in the media queries much much bigger... and maybe use one more wrapper. I'll try and come back to this tomorrow once I get some sleep. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This works in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQbQmN) using the example you provided, although some of the footage is clipped in the video (frame effect);

**html**

```
  <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N9Y86YCRRDg?&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=N9Y86YCRRDg&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;mute=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.vid-info { width: 50%; padding: .5rem; }
.vid-info h1 { margin-bottom: .2rem; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.vid-info .acronym { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: if you reduce the height of the iframe you'll notice that from a certain point the video is not covering the whole iframe anymore

Comment: ahh I seeeee yep

Answer (score 0):

If in case you need you make your iFrame too small and the red play button is becoming too big, you can also follow scaling the iframe wrt to parent approach.

Example Code For React

```
const IFrame = () => {
  const [scaleFactor, setScaleFactor] = useState(1);
  const iFrameRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const parentWidth = iFrameRef.current?.parentElement?.offsetWidth!;
      const iFrameW = parseFloat(iFrameRef.current?.width!);
      setScaleFactor(parentWidth / iFrameW);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize(); // Call once on initial render

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "0px",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50.5%",
        left: "80%",
        width: "16%",
      }}
    >
      <iframe
        ref={iFrameRef}
        className=""
        width={1280/4}
        height={720/4}
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqyUoU0U4BA?autoplay=0&mute=0&controls=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1"
        allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
        allowFullScreen
        style={{
          transform: `scale(${scaleFactor})`,
          transformOrigin: "top left",
        }}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}

export default IFrame;
```